# Running the same SSIS package at the same time with different parameter values

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-job

I have a stored procedure which generates a job which in turn calls a SSIS Package and passes on an operation id variable to the SSIS pacakge. When two users run the SP at exactly the same time the result of the operation is as follows:

user A: receives a blank result
user B: receives his result twice

doing some logging i have found out that the parameters sent are ok when creating the job. However once in the SSIS package the parameters are the same for both operations.

Is there any way to run a SSIS package simultaneously while keeping both sets of parameters independent and returning the corresponding results?

Comment: I would expect the instances of the package to run independently. Could it be a concurrency issue with the proc that generates the job?

Comment: We have logged the variables that get passed to the job and they are different right before creating it so i wouldn't think that's the problem, could it be the number of cores the computer has?

Comment: "Trust, but verify". That is, are the parameters *in the job definitions* actually different? From your comment above, you're saying something like "from what we're logging, they should be different". Take a look at the jobs and confirm what you suspect to be true.

Comment: The script creates the job at runtime and deletes it after it is finished, I have logged the "command" parameter that the job executes and up to that point the variables are different. To set the variable we use Package.Variable[variable_name].Value but i have seen others using something like user::variable_name, are there different scopes? could it be that package variables get overwritten?